# How to keep multiple workstation in sync?

Tags: sync, rsync, multiple-workstations

In my company, over 200 workstation setup in the same network connected to 1Gbps switch. Do you guys have any way to keep them in sync configuration, application upgrade, software installed.

My current design using rsync to keep them in sync by select one of the workstation to be the master. Install software, new configuration then rsync the entire OS partition to other workstation. I have list of workstation name to sync it alphabetically order.

I have been using network mount to share the configuration and apps for a while. It end up with high network load to the share storage event upgrade it to 10gbps NIC. I rather put it locally.

Do you guys have any thought to do this more clever?
I'm looking for something like .deb maker or Git checkout.

Does Ubuntu One have the local maintain version?

Comment: You could just have all the apps and stuff on a main server and just execute it over the network.

Comment: check out landscape (https://landscape.canonical.com), chief (https://www.chef.io), puppet (https://puppetlabs.com), salt (http://saltstack.com). Maybe one of these will fit your needs.